# How to typeset subquestions and the corresponding answers

Tags: packages, exam, exercises, answers, probsoln

I would like to typeset exercises with subquestions so that in the code I have an answer immediately following each subquestion, but in the output all the answers will be in the end. Also I want both exercises and subquestions to be automatically numbered. I know that there are several packages for typesetting exercises (for example 'answers', 'exercise' and 'probsoln'). I also know that there is a document type called 'exam'.

My question is: Which package would work best for this and what kind of code would produce the result?

I would like to write something like the following:

```
\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise{}
    Calculate the following:
    \Question{$7+2$}
      \Answer{$9$}
    \Question{$9-9$}
      \Answer{$0$}
    \Question{$5+5+5$}
      \Answer{$15$}
  \Exercise{}
    Solve the following equations:
    \Question{$x+5=7$}
      \Answer{$x=2$}
    \Question{$x-5=9$}
      \Answer{$x=14$}
    \Question{$5x=20$}
      \Answer{$x=4$}
\end{ExerciseList}
```

And I wan the final document look something like this:

> *Exercise 1*
>  Calculate the following:
>  a) 7+2 b) 9-9
>   c) 5+5+5
>
> *Exercise 2*
>  Solve the following equations:
>  a) x+5=7 b) x-5=9 c)
>   5x=20
>
> **Solutions:**
>
> *Exercise 1*
>  a) 9 b) 0 c) 15
>
> *Exercise 2*
>  a) x+5=7 b) x=14 c) x=4

The code that I have above is just an example. The commands do not have to be exactly as I have written as long as the structure is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `probsoln` package, problems can be defined either within the document or in an external file that can be loaded using a command such as `\loadallproblems` or `\loadrandomproblems`.

Here's a simple example with the problems defined in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}

\begin{defproblem}{prob1}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Calculate the following:%

    \begin{textenum}
    \item $7+2$
    \item $9-9$
    \item $5+5+5$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}% solution
    \begin{textenum}
    \item $9$
    \item $0$
    \item $15$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}

\begin{defproblem}{prob2}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Solve the following equations:

    \begin{textenum}
    \item $x+5=7$
    \item $x-5=9$
    \item $5x=20$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}% solution
    \begin{textenum}
    \item $x=2$
    \item $x=14$
    \item $x=4$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}

\begin{enumerate}
\foreachproblem{\item\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Solutions}

\showanswers
\begin{enumerate}
\foreachsolution{\item\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: Image of document showing problems and the solutions]

The formatting can be changed. For example, using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{defproblem}{prob1}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Calculate the following:%

    \begin{textenum}
    \item $7+2$
    \item $9-9$
    \item $5+5+5$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}% solution
    \begin{textenum}
    \item $9$
    \item $0$
    \item $15$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}

\begin{defproblem}{prob2}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Solve the following equations:

    \begin{textenum}
    \item $x+5=7$
    \item $x-5=9$
    \item $5x=20$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}% solution
    \begin{textenum}
    \item $x=2$
    \item $x=14$
    \item $x=4$
    \end{textenum}
  \end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}

\newenvironment{ExerciseList}
{\begin{enumerate}[label={\emph{Exercise \arabic*}},%
   ref={\arabic*},wide]
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}%
}
{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\exercise}{\item\mbox{}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseList}
\foreachproblem{\exercise\thisproblem}
\end{ExerciseList}

\section*{Solutions}

\showanswers
\begin{ExerciseList}
\foreachsolution{\exercise\thisproblem}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit:**

Here's an alternative where you can write the answer next to the question in the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\QA}[2]{%
  \begin{onlyproblem}#1\end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}#2\end{onlysolution}}

\begin{defproblem}{prob1}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Calculate the following:%

  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{textenum}
    \item \QA{$7+2$}{$9$}
    \item \QA{$9-9$}{$0$}
    \item \QA{$5+5+5$}{$15$}
  \end{textenum}
\end{defproblem}

\begin{defproblem}{prob2}% label
  \begin{onlyproblem}% question
    Solve the following equations:

  \end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{textenum}
    \item \QA{$x+5=7$}{$x=2$}
    \item \QA{$x-5=9$}{$x=14$}
    \item \QA{$5x=20$}{$x=4$}
  \end{textenum}
\end{defproblem}

\newenvironment{ExerciseList}
{\begin{enumerate}[label={\emph{Exercise \arabic*}},%
   ref={\arabic*},wide]
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}%
}
{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\exercise}{\item\mbox{}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseList}
\foreachproblem{\exercise\thisproblem}
\end{ExerciseList}

\section*{Solutions}

\showanswers
\begin{ExerciseList}
\foreachsolution{\exercise\thisproblem}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as the previous example.

**Edit 2:**

Here's a method that defines and displays the problem. The label is generated automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\QA}[2]{%
  \begin{onlyproblem}#1\end{onlyproblem}%
  \begin{onlysolution}#2\end{onlysolution}}

\newenvironment{ExerciseList}
{\begin{enumerate}[label={\emph{Exercise \arabic*}},%
   ref={\arabic*},wide]
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}%
}
{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\exercise}{\item\mbox{}\par}

\newcommand{\Exercise}[2]{\exercise 
 #1\par
 \begin{defproblem}{prob\arabic{enumi}}%
  \begin{textenum}%
  #2%
  \end{textenum}%
 \end{defproblem}%
 \useproblem{prob\arabic{enumi}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseList}
 \Exercise{Calculate the following:}%
 {%
    \item \QA{$7+2$}{$9$}
    \item \QA{$9-9$}{$0$}
    \item \QA{$5+5+5$}{$15$}
 }%

 \Exercise{Solve the following equations:}
 {%
    \item \QA{$x+5=7$}{$x=2$}
    \item \QA{$x-5=9$}{$x=14$}
    \item \QA{$5x=20$}{$x=4$}
 }
\end{ExerciseList}

\section*{Solutions}

\showanswers
\begin{ExerciseList}
\foreachsolution{\exercise\thisproblem}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The output is exactly what I want. However, I would like to have the solution immediately following the question in my source code. The reason is that I want to be able to easily move subquestions around. If the answers are in a separate section, I would have to move the answers separately.

Comment: @ttsc I've made an edit. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. The way you define the QA-command is perfect for me. One more thing: Is it possible to put the questions inside the document environment so that there would be no need for a unique label for each question?

Comment: @ttsc I've made another edit.

Comment: Yes! That works for me and it's very nice and clean. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the `answers` package. You can tinker with the formatting of the answers.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{answers}

\newcommand{\answerFileName}{anexamanswers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{\answerFileName}
\Opensolutionfile{\answerFileName}

\newenvironment{Exercise}[1]
{\item #1
\begin{enumerate}
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{%
\item #1
}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\begin{Exercise}{Calculate the following:}
    \Question{$7+2$}
     \begin{sol}
         $9$
     \end{sol}
    \Question{$9-9$}
      \begin{sol}
          $0$
      \end{sol}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}{Solve the following equations:}
    \Question{$x+5=7$}
      \begin{sol}
        $x=2$
     \end{sol}
    \Question{$x-5=9$}
%      \Answer{$x=14$}
    \Question{$5x=20$}
%      \Answer{$x=4$}
\end{Exercise}

\end{enumerate}

\Closesolutionfile{\answerFileName}
\newpage
Answers to Exercises:

\input{\answerFileName}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your solution would work for me. If possible, I would prefer to have the answers set up in a way that would not repeat the exercise number with each sub question - so that for example the exercise number 1 would be displayed only once and that would be followed by "a) 9 b) 0" etc... Is it possible to achieve this with the 'answers' package?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using the `exsheets` and `tasks` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets,tasks}
\SetupExSheets{
  solution/name=Exercise ,
  headings-format=\itshape
}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Calculate the following:
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $7+2$
    \task $9-9$
    \task $5+5+5$
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $9$
    \task $0$
    \task $15$
  \end{tasks}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Solve the following equations:
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $x+5=7$
    \task $x-5=9$
    \task $5x=20$
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $x=2$
    \task $x=14$
    \task $x=4$
  \end{tasks}
\end{solution}

\section*{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]